# “Include in Project” option missing from folder context menu in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am running Visual Studio 2017 . I am unable to add files in the project because the “Include in Project” option is missing from folder context menu in Visual Studio 2017.[Screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfEJV.png)

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot of your context menu & solution explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the top most part of the project, select the solution. Press show all files.
[image: image here]

Then clicking those will include the excluded projects/files then right click the File with these icon
 [image: icon]

Then click include in project

[image: include project]